# ESB and Java application communication using SOAP WS

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, esb

I am planing to use SOAP web services as a medium to communicate between J2ee application and ESB. Is it a good idea to use SOAP ? What other options I can look for ? 
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to use SOAP ?

It's based on your requirement, WSO2 ESB supports SOAP 1.1, SOAP 1.2 message formats.

> What other options I can look for ?

WSO2 ESB features connecting anything to anything. Following are the formats and protocols. For more details, check the introduction [page](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/)

**Features**

Connecting Anything to Anything

- **Transports:** HTTP, HTTPS, POP, IMAP, SMTP, JMS, AMQP, FIX, TCP, UDP,
  FTPS, SFTP, CIFS, MLLP, SMS
- **Formats & protocols:** JSON, XML, SOAP 1.1, SOAP 1.2, WS-*, HTML, EDI,
  HL7, OAGIS, Hessian, Text, JPEG, MP4, All binary formats, CORBA/IIOP
- **Adapters to COTS systems:** SAP BAPI & IDoc, PeopleSoft, MS Navision,
  IBM WebSphere MQ, Oracle AQ, MSMQ
- **Adapters to cloud services:** Salesforce, Paypal, LinkedIn, Twitter,
  JIRA

Comment: Does ESB support REST / RESTful Web services ? iI read somewhere that ESB can support REST also. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-RESTesb/index.html?ca=dat

Comment: @Blackberrydev : Yes, WSO2 ESB support RESTfull web services as well. Check the documentation here : https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Using+the+REST+API

Comment: Why WSO2 ESB? I don't see that the Blackberry Dev asked for this. Looks like marketing.

Comment: @Spakendraloman : Why it can't be? And moreover, OP accept this asnwer as it suit his/her needs.

Comment: He asked if SOAP is OK. You told him to use WSO2. Which is OK, but this is not a good answer.

Comment: @spakendraloman : Where did he mentioned about blackberry development other than in his name? Honestly, I don't understand your problem here

Comment: @Abimaran Kugathasan: 1. Blackberry Dev is his name. I'm not saying he mentioned it. 2. Now about your answer. He asked if SOAP is OK. You told him WSO2 supports SOAP. I don't see that he is looking for an ESB. Your answer has no connection with the question.

Comment: @Spakendraloman : He asked about communication between his application and an ESB. So, I helped him that, WSO2 ESB support communication over SOAP and he can use it. What do you mean by `SOAP is OK?` OK for what? Did you read the question carefully? Some ESBs are not supporting SOAP.

Comment: "Is SOAP OK" = "Is it a good idea to use SOAP ?" Now please show me where do you explain to him weather this is a good idea or not, besides the "It's based on your requirement"

Comment: @spakendraloman : Check my answer for that question. I just suggest him to use WSO2 ESB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what you need. First think about your resources, who will use them and in what way. 
For instance, if you're just communicating between two systems, than SOAP might be fine: you'll have a structured service, you'll have the chance to build your client and server side quickly, etc. This is because you'll be probbably using the same technology on both sides. 
But as another example, if you think there will be hudreds of developers making their APIs for your service, then you might think about implementing a RESTfull service, which will be easier to use for them.

Secondly, I guess you were speaking of SOAP over HTTP. You could do SOAP over some other protocol. A popular choice is JMS, for instance, which will let you handle transactions. Again, you should think about what you want to implement..